# Scroll the element that I focusing on up when keyboard appears on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I working with Reactjs, and have multiple TextInput in my app.
When clicking/focusing on that to input, keyboard popup (on mobile). I want the input form to scroll to the top of the page when keyboard appears. But I wasn't able to do that.
I tried it with scrollIntoView but it doesn't seem to work correctly all the time.

Please help me if you have a more optimal solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.